why the command in ffmpeg with dshow is not working ? i can't list devices and can't capture/record audio only video. using windows 10 pro
I want to capture video and audio.  I can capture video no problems but I can't capture the audio, and when I type thw list_devices command i get this error:
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy

[dshow @ 000002760c57f200] Could not enumerate video devices (or none found).
[dshow @ 000002760c57f200] Could not enumerate audio only devices (or none found).
[in#0 @ 000002760c57ee00] Error opening input: Immediate exit requested
Error opening input file dummy.

For the video capture I use this:
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 24 -i desktop -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4

What do I need to do to also capture also the audio from the speakers? I tried this but it's not working:
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="UScreenCapture" -f dshow -i audio="Microphone" output.mkv


[dshow @ 000002553861f280] Could not enumerate video devices (or none found).
[in#0 @ 000002553861ee80] Error opening input: I/O error
Error opening input file video=UScreenCapture.
Error opening input files: I/O error

And the Stereo Mix on my windows 10 is enabled already.

Try using ffmpeg-release-full. version 7.1 from here. When enabling Stereo Mix, In my machine executing ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy prints: @device_cm_{...} [Stereo Mix (Realtek High Definition Audio)] (audio). For debugging, you may download GraphStudioNext 64-Bit from here. Execute, goto: Graph -> Insert Audio Source and look for "Stereo Mix". Is it listed?
